# Do github pages sites have static ip addresses

Tags: github, ip

I am creating a github pages site by branching a gh-pages version off of my repository. Its url ends up being

```
myusername.github.io/myRepoName/
```

If I am hosting the project like this during development, will the IP address remain static?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted answer has outdated IP addresses. Try the ones below.

185.199.108.153

185.199.109.153

185.199.110.153

185.199.111.153

Comment: You are missing the ipv6 records: 2606:50c0:8000::153
2606:50c0:8001::153
2606:50c0:8002::153
2606:50c0:8003::153

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're trying to set up a CNAME for this Github pages.

[Click here](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site#configuring-an-apex-domain) for their documentations.

While the IP isn't static, these 2 IPs in unison should work:

```
192.30.252.153
192.30.252.154
```